# Issues installing matlab on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to install Matlab 2012b on 12.04 64 bit system. I tried `sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012B/install` and got the following error message.

```
Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_4131/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: 4: /tmp/mathworks_4131/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Finished
```

What can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the contents of the *.iso file? If you did so, then edit that using UltraISO in Windows, then install in ubuntu.